# I want to input character and integers by scanf into a structure

Tags: c++, struct, char, scanf

Ok, so I'd like to input a one-letter character and three numbers into a structure using scanf, and I want to print all four of them by using a function that prints it. But everytime i run it i get errors saying that i can't run it, or sometimes it prints everything right except the character part, where it would just go as blank.. what could be possibly wrong with this??

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Score
{
    char a;
    float x, y, z;
};




void main(void)
{

void avg(char *a, float x, float y, float z);


    char a1 = 'b';
    float x1 = 0, y1 = 0, z1 = 0;

    printf("enter an alphaber\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf_s("%c", &a1);
    printf("enter three numbers (ex:1,2,3)\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf_s("%f,%f,%f", &x1, &y1, &z1);



    struct Score s1 = { a1, x1, y1, z1 };



    avg(s1.a, s1.x, s1.y, s1.z);



}
void avg(char *a, float x, float y, float z)
{
    printf("%c (%f,%f,%f) \n", a, x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()` in function `avg()`: `%c` calls for `int`, but `a` has type `char*`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, then what can i replace c with??? sry im totally new to  c++

Comment: is there any good reason why you use `scanf` / `printf` instead if `iostream`s ?

Comment: Are you studying C or C++? Which compiler are you using? No C++ compiler should compile this program, see e.g. [this set of error messages](http://ideone.com/0s5Djw) or [this one](http://rextester.com/GHQK4737). Some C compilers will accept it with warnings. You should never ignore warnings. Always treat warnings as errors. BTW studying `scanf` and `printf` and pointers is not a good way to learn C++.

Comment: Is there any reason this is tagged as C++? There's nothing C++-ish to this code.

Comment: BTW, the `fflush` does not work with `stdin`.  You can't flush the input buffer.

Comment: Why are you using a structure if you are passing the individual elements to your `avg` function?  I recommend passing the structure or passing individual variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `avg()` is wrong. The first argument should be not `char*` but `char`.

Because I hate MSVC-specific code, your code should be like this.
Note that you should check whether readings are successful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Score
{
    char a;
    float x, y, z;
};

int main(void)
{

    /* declareing function inside function is unusual, but not bad */
    void avg(char a, float x, float y, float z);

    char a1 = 'b';
    float x1 = 0, y1 = 0, z1 = 0;

    printf("enter an alphaber\n");
    if (scanf("%c", &a1) != 1) {
        puts("read error");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("enter three numbers (ex:1,2,3)\n");
    if (scanf("%f,%f,%f", &x1, &y1, &z1) != 3) {
        puts("read error");
        return 1;
    }

    struct Score s1 = { a1, x1, y1, z1 };

    avg(s1.a, s1.x, s1.y, s1.z);

}

void avg(char a, float x, float y, float z)
{
    printf("%c (%f,%f,%f) \n", a, x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: Just nitpicking, but you should avoid `scanf("%c", &a1)` unless you really want to be able to read a space. I generally prefere `char dummy[2]; scanf("%1s", dummy); a1 = *dummy;`

Comment: and also i was wondering.. what i could use when i want to type in an array of characters instead of just one-letter alphabet like shown above. do i use %s and char[] to do that?? thnx

Comment: use `scanf(" %c", &a1);` if you want to read a non-whitespace character and skip whitespace first.  Use `%Xs` to read a string into a buffer, where `X` is an integer denoting one less than the size of the buffer (the maximum number of characters to read -- leaving space for a trailing NULL byte)